# Can I migrate from Blogger to WordPress?

Tags: blogger

Can I migrate all content from Blogger to WordPress? images etc? My website is: https://www.interlibros.org and is there a difference if I do it on free WordPress or WordPress on a paid server? Thank you!

Comment: I've never done this, but I suspect this is a well-solved problem. You might as well just try it and see if you run into any issues? You can migrate to a new site without taking the original site down, and remigrate later. The only difference free or paid hosting would make would be how much access you have to install migration tools, if you need to install extra ones - sometimes paid hosts give you less access so that they can restrict what they need to support. (But then they'd be eager for new customers so should be happy to help.)

Comment: Paid / free is more likely to affect how the site performs after the migration, and / or how much data you're allowed to store if you have very large volumes of images, rather than the migration itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - here is a very clear guide on how to do this

https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-switch-from-blogger-to-wordpress-without-losing-google-rankings/